# How do I remove repeated values from column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database. id - is a primary key.

```
id color
1 green
2 red
3 pink
4 pink
5 red
```

How do I remove repeated colors in SQL? The result will be:

```
id color
1 green
2 red
3 pink
```

Comment: Do you want to remove them from your select statement's result, or from your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove duplicates from your table, try a statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM my_table 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM my_table t2
  WHERE my_table.color = t2.color
  AND my_table.id > t2.id
)
```

In English: Delete all records from `my_table` where there is another record in `my_table` with the same colour but  with a lower ID. This will keep the record with the lowest ID per duplicate colour.

I suggest that after removing duplicates, you should add a unique constraint as indicated by [LolCoder here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11599905/521799)

Comment: SQLite doesn't allow aliases in delete statements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601577/i-have-a-sqlite-syntax-error

Comment: @Voloda2: Whoops, I wasn't aware of that. Does it work the way I have written it now?

Comment: Yep, it works. I have a question. SELECT 1 FROM it means SELECT color FROM?

Comment: @Voloda2: No, it means `SELECT 1 FROM`. As in "the number one". You can also write `SELECT color FROM` of course, as the `EXISTS` clause doesn't really care about the projected fields in the subquery...

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `DISTINCT` to find the distinct item in following way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(color) FROM colors
```

If you want to remove repeated color from table,

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE colors ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(color);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to remove duplicate values from the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DISTINCT()`-statement to achieve this.
For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(color) FROM colors";
```

**More info**

The DISTINCT clause allows you to remove duplicates from the result set. The DISTINCT clause can only be used with select statements.

Source: [TECH on the net](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php)