# I have a SQLite syntax error in DELETE statement

Tags: macos, sqlite

I have a very strange sqlite syntax error.

```
const char *statement = "DELETE FROM quotes t1 WHERE t1.id=127";
int returnCode = sqlite3_exec(database, statement, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);
if (returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s", errorMsg);
    sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
}

 Error: near "t1": syntax error
```

But this code works well

```
const char *statement = "DELETE FROM quotes WHERE id=127";
int returnCode = sqlite3_exec(database, statement, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite doesn't allow aliases in delete statements.

See the [manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) for the allowed syntax.

---

[**delete-stmt**](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#delete-stmt)

[image]

[**qualified-table-name**](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#qualified-table-name)

[image]